# Given data points and y value, give x value

Tags: r, interpolation

Given a set of (x,y) coordinates, how can I solve for x, from y. If you were to plot the coordinates, they would be non-linear, but pretty close to exponential. I tried `approx()`, but it is way off. Here is example data. In this scenario, how could I solve for `y == 50`?

> ```
>   V1      V3
> ```
>
> 1    5.35 11.7906
>
> 2   10.70 15.0451
>
> 3   16.05 19.4243
>
> 4   21.40 20.7885
>
> 5   26.75 22.0584
>
> 6   32.10 25.4367
>
> 7   37.45 28.6701
>
> 8   42.80 30.7500
>
> 9   48.15 34.5084
>
> 10  53.50 37.0096
>
> 11  58.85 39.3423
>
> 12  64.20 41.5023
>
> 13  69.55 43.4599
>
> 14  74.90 44.7299
>
> 15  80.25 46.5738
>
> 16  85.60 47.7548
>
> 17  90.95 49.9749
>
> 18  96.30 51.0331
>
> 19 101.65 52.0207
>
> 20 107.00 52.9781
>
> 21 112.35 53.8730
>
> 22 117.70 54.2907
>
> 23 123.05 56.3025
>
> 24 128.40 56.6949
>
> 25 133.75 57.0830
>
> 26 139.10 58.5051
>
> 27 144.45 59.1440
>
> 28 149.80 60.0687
>
> 29 155.15 60.6627
>
> 30 160.50 61.2313
>
> 31 165.85 61.7748
>
> 32 171.20 62.5587
>
> 33 176.55 63.2684
>
> 34 181.90 63.7085
>
> 35 187.25 64.0788
>
> 36 192.60 64.5807
>
> 37 197.95 65.2233
>
> 38 203.30 65.5331
>
> 39 208.65 66.1200
>
> 40 214.00 66.6208
>
> 41 219.35 67.1952
>
> 42 224.70 67.5270
>
> 43 230.05 68.0175
>
> 44 235.40 68.3869
>
> 45 240.75 68.7485
>
> 46 246.10 69.1878
>
> 47 251.45 69.3980
>
> 48 256.80 69.5899
>
> 49 262.15 69.7382
>
> 50 267.50 69.7693
>
> 51 272.85 69.7693
>
> 52 278.20 69.7693
>
> 53 283.55 69.7693
>
> 54 288.90 69.7693

Comment: There are no rows of your data frame for which `y==50`, so you will have to do some kind of interpolation. Fit a model to your data and proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the problem you have is that `approx` solves for `y` given `x`, while you are talking about solving for `x` given `y`. So you need to switch your variables `x` and `y` when using `approx`:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("

V1      V3
85.60 47.7548
90.95 49.9749
96.30 51.0331
101.65 52.0207

"), header = TRUE)

approx(x = df$V3, y = df$V1, xout = 50)
# $x
# [1] 50
# 
# $y
# [1] 91.0769
```

Also, if `y` is exponential with respect to `x`, then you have a linear relationship between `x` and `log(y)`, so it makes more sense to use a linear interpolator between `x` and `log(y)`, then take the exponential to get back to `y`:

```
exp(approx(x = df$V3, y = log(df$V1), xout = 50)$y)
# [1] 91.07339
```

Comment: Wow how embarrassing. I definitely switched x and y. That's what I get for drinking and programming :)